# How to install ssl certificate for push notification?

Tags: ios, certificate, push-notification

I have an issue with my push notification system for an app for ios: it works perfectly in development, but isn't working in production.
Now i have a doubt. Here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html
i read that the pem certificate must be "installed" on the server.

While developing, i've only copied the development .pem on the same directory of the php script that send the push notifications, and made the script use it. In production (my app is live on the app store) i must "install" in some way the distribution .pem on the server?

Note: To verify that all goes in the right way i do:

```
   $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
 if(!$fp){
     print "All ok!";
 }
```

and

```
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    print "sending message :" . $payload . "n to device:".$deviceToken."</br>";
    $result=fwrite($fp, $msg);
    if (!$result)
        print "All ok!":
}
```

And even in production, the two did not fire any error.

Comment: I use the two piece of code i wrote in the edit to verify the socket opening. Are they ok? They not fire any error. The device token seems to be the production one, for i installed from the app store the app on my ipad, made my php script write the token received by the app in this way into my database and then send the push with no luck. In my target, Code Signing Identity for the release i have the profile bearing my company name and the "Iphone Distribution". It's ok? Is this the problem: all seems to be ok. It's been two days that i'm struggling with this. It's driving me mad ^^''

Comment: Oh, well, the problem is that all seems to go in the right way but no notification arrive on any device. I tried also a fresh install on a device on which i'd never installed the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need more than copy your ssl certificate on the server and reference it from your scripts to install it.

My problem was that in the db containing my device tokens, which send the notification to, there were some device token generated by my development devices. If you send a development token to the production apple server it kills the connection, avoiding you to send any other notification on the same connection. Thank you very much apple server!